# Code review tool which allows to review branches, not just diffs

Tags: code-review

Currently we're using GitHub PR system for code reviews. This approach works quite well for us, but sometimes it's not so good. Especially when it comes to the need to review a larger change, and being able to comment not only the diff, but also the code on branch itself.

Can anyone suggest something here?